# Which filesystem will give me the best performance for both writing and reading small files?

Tags: linux, filesystems

My company developed an application that picks up (watches for) xml files of  <10kb in size from a directory, reads it in sends the body as an api call to an external service and then moves the file into a processed directory.

Due to the volume of files - roughly 2000/min we were getting dreadful performance out of NTFS. We were no where near able to keep up with the processing.

I'm a Linux guy through and through and from experience Linux would handle this situation a lot better especially with things like inotify which are leaps and bounds ahead of the ntfs api, that's why I've ported the code to .NET Core to give it a shot.

At home I use XFS on my Workstations and ZFS on my servers, so aside from ext4 - I have no real experience with any other filesystem.

So my question is - which filesystem (preferably in-tree) would be the most performant for this kind of workload.

Comment: Just try ext4. Don't over optimise early.

Comment: What about the hardware (the drive, where your file system will reside)?

Comment: Currently it's on hyper-v with shared vhdx, it's going to move over to ESXi - I don't know the exact specs of the hypervisor.

Comment: If the data is small in relation to the amount of memory then I would look at tmpfs; basically a RAMdisk.  It's non-persistent, but is great for temporary files.  So code your primary loop to work from tmpfs, and then have a batch (once an hour?) move processed files to persistent storage (if it's needed).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor It is probably nearly impossible for the OP to change his root filesystem.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-is-the-most-high-performance-linux-filesystem-for-storing-a-lot-of-small-fi

Comment: @peterh if the OP could not change it, then they would not ask.

Comment: @StephenHarris what you are describing is caching. You will probably not be better at it then the kernel is: once you have read the data, it will all be in ram (cached). It will only fall out of cache if the data set is large.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor No.. tmpfs is different to caching.

Comment: @StephenHarris yes a little, but.